# GNU MP Temporary/Scratch Memory Usage

Tags: c, memory, valgrind, gmp

I've been trying to measure how much temporary memory GNU MP is using with valgrind's massif tool with the option `--stacks=yes`. Valgrind is reporting 0 heap usage throughout the entire program and only stack usage.

In order to measure temporary memory usage, I've tried reconfiguring GMP MP Library by switching `--enable-alloca` from `yes` to `no` to shift the temporary memory onto the heap instead of stack, but it doesn't seem to result in any significant differences in stack usage data outputted by massif.

My peak physical RAM usage when I run my particular program is 3 times as large as the input and output combined, and I'm simply multiplying integers. This leads me to suspect that scratch/temporary space is a large portion of the RAM usage. How can I best profile temporary memory usage continuously throughout the running of the program?

Comment: Paul Zimmermann states, " Fast multiplication algorithms like FFT imply a
larger memory usage. Very roughly for a n x n product, you need two
buffers of size about 4n, thus the extra memory usage is 8n (in
addition to the space needed for the inputs and outputs)" in https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2016-June/006009.html which gives a nice estimate of memory usage by large input multiplication.